# DocumentBuilderFactory removing namespaces, even with #setNamespaceAware

Tags: java, xml, namespaces

I'm trying to convert an XML string to a Document, do some DOM manipulation, then convert it back to a string. But I'm having trouble getting the namespaces to be retained after the tranformation. I'd like to keep the namespace for child elements which have the same namespace as the parent.

I'm running the following simple code to test:

```
final String test = "<element xmlns:xc=\"urn:myNamespace\">\n"
        + "\t<child xmlns:xc=\"urn:myNamespace\">\n"
        + "\t\t<attribute>value</attribute>\n"
        + "\t</child>\n"
        + "</element>\n";

System.out.println(test);

final DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = mentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
documentBuilderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
final Document testDoc = documentBuilderFactory
        .newDocumentBuilder()
        .parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(test.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));

final StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
final TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();

final Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "2");

transformer.transform(new DOMSource(testDoc), new StreamResult(stringWriter));
System.out.println(stringWriter.toString());
```

The output is:

```
<element xmlns:xc="urn:myNamespace">
<child xmlns:xc="urn:myNamespace">
    <attribute>value</attribute>
</child>
</element>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<element xmlns:xc="urn:myNamespace">
    <child>
        <attribute>value</attribute>
    </child>
</element>
```

I'm using Java 7. Is there any way to keep the namespace in the child element?